# Override module-contact view and controller

Tags: magento2

I created a new page with the CMS. I paste this in editor:

> {{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm"
>   template="Magento_Theme::html/contact_form.phtml"}}

Then I overrided the **contact_form.phtml** successfully for my theme under

> app/design/fontend/MyThemes/2016/Magento_Theme/templates/html/

Submitting the form send to this controller `vendor/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php`

Route used in this controller is `$this->_redirect('contact/index');` which is not the page I created with the cms.

My Question now is, **how to override the controller**?

I tried by creating the file under `app/code/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php`, but no success.

```
<?php    
namespace Magento\Contact\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index
{
    public function execute()
    {
        die('pass here?');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please put our override code?

Comment: @arsenik how to change the subject for contact us form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create small module for this.

Using *di.xml* can *rewrite the controller* **Post.php**

**First** ,*Create module registration file* `registration.php` at **app\code\VendorName\ModuleName**. Code is below:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Then** create module main config ***`module.xml`*** file at **app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\etc**. Code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**3rd,** create ***`di.xml`*** where you define configuration that which *class will rewrite and which class rewriting*  and **di.xml** located at 
**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\etc** and code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index\Post" />
</config>
```

**4th,** write the *rewrite class* which located  at `Post.php` **app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index**.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('YOUR_CMS_PAGE_Identifier'); // change here 
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('YOUR_CMS_PAGE_Identifier');  // change here 
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

- Now you need to enable *`php bin/magento module:status`*

  *`php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_ModuleName`* for enable the module.
- and run  ***`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`*** for enabled modules
  are properly registered.

Then clear cache.

**NOte:This module is tested**

Comment: VendorName\ModuleName can be MyThemes\2016?

Comment: yes it can but note that  location  should be app/code

Comment: what is AmitBera_CustomContacts ? in module.xml

Comment: Answer updated.. now check

Comment: hi @AmitBera i need one small help how to set custom subject for contact us form in the controller?

Comment: Actually i would like to change the subject for contact us form