# Magento 2 : Overriding Default Contact Form Controller POST.php file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email, controllers, contact-form

I'm trying to override the contact form post controller in Magento 2.2.6, by following the answer from this thread ([Override module-contact view and controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119795/override-module-contact-view-and-controller)) by creating my own module. I added `\Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation` to fix some error, but i'm not able to send out the form as expected, keeps getting "We can't process your request right now. Sorry, that's all we know." error. Please help, thanks!

VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Magento\Contact\Index\Post.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Magento\Contact\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post
{
    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        //$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            //$this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact'); // change here 
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //$this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact');  // change here 
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

VendorName\ModuleName\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Magento\Contact\Index\Post" />
</config>
```

VendorName\ModuleName\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: The answer from that thread is quite old and not compatible with your current magento version, so don't copy, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the tips to find the error message, below is my working solution for Magento 2.2.6. 
My goal was to change the setFrom address to be the email address customer entered in the contact form, to integrate with our help desk system which grabs the setFrom address as an customer.

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Magento\Contact\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index
{

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = 'contact/email/recipient_email';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = 'contact/email/sender_email_identity';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'contact/email/email_template';

    private $context;
    private $transportBuilder;
    private $inlineTranslation;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $contactsConfig);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?:
            ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }
            $sender = $post['email'];
            $senderName = $post['name'];
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => 'frontend',
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                //->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->setFrom(
                    [
                    'email' => $post['email'],
                    'name' => $post['name']
                    ]
                )
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'], $post['name']);


            $transport = $transport->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your feedback or questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact'); // change here 
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print echo $e->getMessage() in catch block. By the way there is one more way to do so.

**routes.xml**

```
<!-- File: app/code/Pulsestorm/HelloWorldMVVM/etc/frontend/routes.xml-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="contact">
            <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" before="Magento_Contact"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        //$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            if ($error) {
                throw new \Exception();
            }

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            //$this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact'); // change here 
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //$this->inlineTranslation->resume();
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know. '. $e->getMessage())
            );
            $this->_redirect('contact');  // change here 
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This method is known as route sharing and it will read your module's controller before default controller file. Let me know if any further assistance needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably you cannot send the email with your code

```
$transport->sendMessage();
```

Try to use debugger inside the \Exeption or edit

```
$this->messageManager->addError(
            __('We can\'t process your request right now. Sorry, that\'s all we know. '. $e->getMessage())
        );
```

Into

```
$this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
```

To see the error